# How to iterate javascript objects key-value pairs in salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC and I want to iterate over javascript objects  key-value pair in LWC. The keys in object are dynamic. As LWC iteration doesn't allow computed expression like Obj[key], is there is better way to iterate JS objects key value pairs if keys are not static or fixed.

JS obj:

```
{Id: "0013h000004siUPAAY", Name: "Dickenson plc"}

<template for:each={obj.keys} for:item="key">
               <td key={record.Id}>{obj.key}</td>
</template>
```

Comment: When you say the keys are "dynamic" do you mean that the name of the attribute containing the key is dynamic?

Comment: dynamic keys means keys can be vary in numbers

Comment: And where do they come from? Apex on init?

Comment: keys comes from apex. The JS object is basically a JSON representation of SObject.

Comment: Ah...I think I'm getting you now. It took a minute. The only way I'm thinking of to do that would be to pass each `key` and the whole object into another component and probably have that component deconstruct the key value. But I'll think on it a bit more and see if something comes to mind. In the mean time, _why_ do you want to do this. Sometimes you can get caught in the way of doing something, but it would help to know the why.

Comment: I am just constructing a table dynamically by passing SObject name and fields to component. Here I am using nested Iteration. Outer Iteration Iterates over the record and inner iteration iterates over the fields of record